# Topological , Homeomorphic version of $|S \times S|=|S| $

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Give example of a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ such that with respect to some topology , $ A$ is homeomorphic to $A\times A$ .

In set theory ZF it is known to be equivalent to A.C. that for any infinite set $S$ , there is a bijection between $S$ and $S \times S$ , what would be a suitable homeomorphic(topology) version of this theorem ?

Comment: Are you interested primarily in finding such an $A$, or in the question in the second paragraph?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Well , kind of both

Comment: You can let $A$ be a single element.

Comment: A less trivial example than Isaac's and arovai's is you can consider an arbitrary topological space $X$ and consider the product space of countably many copies of $X$. The resulting space will be isomorphic to the product with itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trivial examples are a one-point subspace and an infinite discrete subspace of $\Bbb R$. The simplest non-trivial examples for $A$ are the rationals, the Cantor set, the irrationals, and the Cantor set minus any one of its points: each is homeomorphic to its square. In none of these cases is this entirely trivial to prove.

- The Cantor set is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology; this is a fairly common exercise and not *enormously* difficult to prove. It’s easy to show that $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ is homeomorphic to its square.
- The irrationals are homeomorphic to $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$; this is a bit harder to prove than the fact that the Cantor set is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$. However, it’s easy to show that $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ is homeomorphic to its square.
- Every countable metric space without isolated points is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$, and $\Bbb Q^2$ is a countable metric space without isolated points, so $\Bbb Q$ is homeomorphic to its square. The characterization theorem isn’t exactly hard, but it’s certainly not trivial, either.
- The Cantor set minus a point is homeomorphic to $\Bbb N\times C$, where $C$ is the Cantor set. Thus, its square is homeomorphic to $(\Bbb N\times C)\times(\Bbb N\times C)$, which in turn is homeomorphic to $\Bbb N^2\times C^2$ and hence to $\Bbb N\times C$.

---

For the general question, note that if $X$ is an infinite space with the discrete topology, then $X\times X$ is homeomorphic to $X$ if and only if $|X\times X|=|X|$: any homeomorphism between $X\times X$ and $X$ is a bijection, and conversely.

Comment: @arovai: Who said anything about *isomorphic*? $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ certainly is *homeomorphic* to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @arovai: Then you’re simply mistaken.

Comment: @arovai: It’s a very well-known result, due to Sierpiński. [This article](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.htm) has a nice write-up.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Could you please just explain  " if $X$ is an infinite space with discrete topology then any bijection between them is a hmeomorphism "

Comment: @user123733: Let $X$ and $Y$ be any discrete spaces, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a bijection. Then $f$ is continuous, since $f^{-1}[U]$ is open for every $U\subseteq Y$, and $f$ is open, since $f[U]$ is open for every $U\subseteq Y$. Thus, $f$ is a homeomorphism. Remember, in a discrete space *every* set is open.

Comment: While I missed the original comment, do note that $\Bbb{Q\times Q}$, as an ordered set with the lexicographic order, is in fact isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$.